Volatility smile vs Vol of Vol smile
Is the vol of vol smile due to the correlation spot/vol similarly to vol smile ?
It seems that if we see the correl as the impact of vol on spot we get the vol smile. And if we see the same correl as an impact of spot on vol we get the vol of vol smile.
Concretely, a huge move in the vol contribute to the vol smile and huge move in the spot contribute to the vol of vol smile.
Are we talking about the same quadratic covariance here ?

What is the vol-of-vol smile? Could you send me somewhere to get info on that?

Doesn't the vol smile (FX) exist because of the risk adverseness of investors? (that invest in OTM options) What does the correlation spot/vol have to do with it? (since you are linking the vol-of-vol smile to it).

@KaiSqDist from a modelling perspective it’s the correlation spot/vol that will produce the skew of the smile. The economic interpretation is another thing.

@MatsLind you can look for SVJJ models.. It is stochastic vol model with double jumps.. The vol is allowed to jump in addition to the spot (Merton model)… Not sure if vol of vol smile is mentioned yet

You mean if you back out the vol smile from SVJJ models the skew is more convex?
